# Odoo 8 - Computed field doesn't use self.env nor searches

Tags: python, odoo

I have a method in my model that works completely fine when I call it through a button, but, whenever it's triggered by a computed field I have in the same model it fails to execute all the code inside it for reasons I don't know. Even after this happens, if I call the method again through the button it works without problem. I've tried googling the issue but haven't had luck. Here's the portion of my code that has the issue.

```
class recibos(models.Model):
_name = "tecnop.recibos"
_rec_name = "num_recibo"

num_recibo = fields.Integer('Número de recibo', size=20)
fecha = fields.Date('Fecha')
# Conecta con módulo de productos
ids_productos = fields.One2many('tecnop.productos', 'id_producto', 'Productos')

# Relación con módulo de proveedores
ids_proveedores = fields.Many2one('tecnop.proveedores', 'Proveedor')
total = fields.Float('Total', size=400, readonly=True, store=True, compute='calcular_total')
subtotal = fields.Float('Subtotal', size=400, readonly=True)
impuesto_total = fields.Float('Impuesto', size=400, readonly=True)

@api.multi
@api.depends('ids_productos.nombre', 'ids_productos.precio')
def calcular_total(self):
    registros = self.env['tecnop.productos'].search([('id_producto', '=', self.id)]) 
    self.total = 0
    self.impuesto_total = 0
    self.subtotal = 0
    for registro in registros:
        if registro.precio:
            impuestos = self.env['tecnop.impuestos'].search([('id_impuesto', '=', registro.id)]) 
            for impuesto in impuestos:
                if impuesto.impuesto:
                    registro.impuesto = registro.precio * impuesto.impuesto
                    self.total = (registro.precio * registro.cantidad) + self.total
                    self.impuesto_total = registro.impuesto + self.impuesto_total
                    self.subtotal = self.total - self.impuesto_total
```

The variable "registros" doesn't get any field from the compute field of "total" whenever it's triggered from there. It just sets all the fields to 0 and doesn't do anything else. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering why it even works without errors, because you use `self` 7 times in a `api.multi` decorated method. The buttons works well with it, because it's always calling the method with a singleton. But computed methods can call the methods with multiple records at once.

So rewrite the method to a multiple record method. It should be enough to use the decorator `api.one`, but it's possible that the button won't work with it anymore.

Another solution is to implement another foreach loop at the beginning of the method `for record in self:` and use `record` instead of `self` afterwards.